# Which design pattern to use to store streams of objects of different types to disk in go?

Tags: design-patterns, go, refactoring

Consider a function that saves streams of objects of different types to disk:

```
func Save(fill func(c chan BaseType), file string) {}
```

This function is used in the following way throughout the code:

```
// Here we've got different data structures data1, data2, ...
// that must be stored to disk
Save(
  func(c chan BaseType) {
    // SaveChildren1 generates objects of type Child1 based
    // on the data1 data structure
    SaveChildren1(c, data1) 
  },
  filename1)

Save(
  func(c chan BaseType) {
    // SaveChildren2 generates objects of type Child2 based
    // on the data2 data structure
    SaveChildren2(c, data2)
  },
  filename2)
```

And so on. There are a lot of different child types and each requires it's own generator -- a function SaveChildren1, SaveChildren2 etc. These functions actually fill the channels with objects.

The question is how would you refactor these "binders" -- the functions that transform SaveChildren (a function of 2 args) into a function of 1 argument? Currently this code doesn't look like a well written go-style code.

Comment: Can you explain why `c` is even passed into `SaveChildren`? After I convert `data1` to some binary what use do I have for a channel that I can send the `BaseType` on? If you're downcasting these 'child types' (there is no inheritance in go so I'm not positive what that means) to the base type then sending the result back on a channel, you're doing it wrong. Pretty sure you can just define the serialization contract in a way that makes that unnecessary. Even if that isn't the case I can't imagine why the channel wouldn't be of type `[]byte`.

Comment: In case you've overlooked them: I would considering having the objects implement either [`encoding/BinaryMarshaler`](https://godoc.org/encoding#BinaryMarshaler) or [`io/WriterTo`](https://godoc.org/io#WriterTo). Additionally, you may find [`gob`](https://godoc.org/encoding/gob) useful.

Answer (score 3):

The gob package seems like a good solution for your problem. There is a great [article on the Go blog](http://blog.golang.org/gobs-of-data) that explains how and why. A short excerpt:

> The gob package was designed with a number of goals in mind.
>
> First, and most obvious, it had to be very easy to use. First, because
>   Go has reflection, there is no need for a separate interface
>   definition language or "protocol compiler". The data structure itself
>   is all the package should need to figure out how to encode and decode
>   it. On the other hand, this approach means that gobs will never work
>   as well with other languages, but that's OK: gobs are unashamedly
>   Go-centric.
>
> Efficiency is also important. Textual representations, exemplified by
>   XML and JSON, are too slow to put at the center of an efficient
>   communications network. A binary encoding is necessary.
>
> Gob streams must be self-describing. Each gob stream, read from the
>   beginning, contains sufficient information that the entire stream can
>   be parsed by an agent that knows nothing a priori about its contents.
>   This property means that you will always be able to decode a gob
>   stream stored in a file, even long after you've forgotten what data it
>   represents.

Further down the article is an example that shows how easy it is to use and how versatile it is.